# Typescript 2 dynamically adding promises to Promise.all()

Tags: promise, typescript2.2

I have been using a promise function to load a single asset (jsfiles,css, etc) into my code. For example :

```
loadScript = (JSFile: string): Promise<any> => { .... }
```

Now I want to be able to load multiple assets using Promise.all(). I would like to create the Promise.all() input array dynamically:

```
let pa: Array<any> = [];
for (let x = 0; x < assetArray.length; x++) {
 if (assetArray[x].use) {
      pa.push( this.loadScript(assetArray[x].name));
 }
Promise.all(pa).then(() => {resolve();});
```

From this snippet above, I suspect that the approach of loading the pa array is actually executing the loadscript functions before the Promise.all() is called and the Promise.all() benefits a running in parallel per the gitbooks link:
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/promise.html are not being realized.

How can I load the pa array in the loop above and then call the Promises.all()?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Was there a solution found for this ?